# Jailbreaking an iPad 2 with iOS 5

Tags: jailbreak, ios, ipad

Is it possible to jailbreak an iPad 2 running iOS 5? Please let me know if it's possible. If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the answer is no. It is fairly widely known that the A5 is a fairly difficult nut to crack.

References:

- [The Dev Team Pwnage tool info](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/4332841631/three-years-of-pwnage-tool)

> The 4.3.1 untether works on all devices that actually support 4.3.1
>   except for the iPad2:
>
> - iPhone3GS
> - iPhone4 (GSM)
> - iPod touch 3G
> - iPod touch 4G
> - iPad1
> - AppleTV 2G (PwnageTool only for now)

- [Cult of Mac Post On iOS 5 Jailbreaks](http://www.cultofmac.com/123262/the-ios-5-jailbreak-is-here-but-iphone-4s-and-ipad-2-owners-need-not-apply/)

> As for the iPhone 4S and iPad 2, both devices run Apple’s new A5
>   processor, which is proving to be an absolute bitch to jailbreak. Only
>   the iPad 2 can be jailbroken under iOS 4.3.3 using the userland
>   JailBreakMe v3 exploit. If the iPad 2 is any example to go by, don’t
>   expect the iPhone 4S to be jailbroken any time soon.